# Retrieve Crystal Report Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report File and I want to know what's the name of the Stored Procedure that is being used on the Report. How can I retrieve it through the code behind. Is this possible?

C# code would be better since I do coding in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're just interested in getting the name of the SP, then there are a couple different ways to tackle this:

<kbd>**If you have Crystal Reports...**</kbd>

1. Open the **Set Datasource Location** dialog. On the bottom pane will be a tree-view of the available database objects, including the list of stored procedures. The highlighted SP will be the one it is calling to retrieve data for the report.
2. If that doesn't help (ie: there's no highlighted Stored Procedure), then ight-click in the report designer area, select `Database -> Show SQL Query`.  This will display the query used to retrieve data from your database. It will possibly have the name of a stored procedure in it.

<kbd>**If you DON'T have Crystal Reports...**</kbd>

- Use [this code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/loadingcrystalreport.aspx) from [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/loadingcrystalreport.aspx) to load your report into C# and traverse the report from there. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/loadingcrystalreport.aspx
- If that doesn't help (ie: you're not ready to tackle the C# aspect of Crystal Reports), then you can use your database's profiling tool to spy on the calls from your report to see which SP(s) it is calling to get the data it needs to run the report. SQL Server's `SQL Profiler` is a good tool for just that purpose. Here are some tutorials to help get you going:

  - Microsoft MSDN: **ARTICLE** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx
  - Tech Republic: **ARTICLE** http://www.techrepublic.com/article/step-by-step-an-introduction-to-sql-server-profiler/5054787
  - SQLServerPedia: **VIDEO** http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Using_SQL_Server_Profiler

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not a way to do this programmatically. You can see the datasource, set the datasource, but you cannot retrieve the actual SQL being used to generate the report other than through the Crystal Reports designer.

Comment: Actually, you can programmatically get the actual SQL used to generate the report using the `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine` Namespace. Check out the `SQLExpressionFieldDefinition` class, it contains all the information you'll need, including the actual SQL expression text. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms226202(v=VS.90).aspx.

Comment: Doh, my mistake! Thanks, I actually have needed to do this before too :)

Comment: :) Crystal Reports is REALLY tricky stuff.  I struggle most times to make heads-or-tails of their API, which they seem to change every release. hehe.